# how to set PATH variable correctly

Tags: windows, path, command-line

I have some problems with setting my user variable PATH, my PATH contains the following line:

```
%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\K-Lite Codec Pack\Media Player Classic";C:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell
```

but when I run `mpc-hc.exe` from the command line I receive `"mpc-hc.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command`, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: no, assume that I run "system" function on C

Comment: You said "when I run mpc-hc.exe from the command line". Make your mind up. Anyway, you don't set environment variables like that from code. From code you use the programmatic interface.

Comment: also while set path=%path%;... makes sense , to have a permanent variable for path, with %path% in the value, sounds nonsensical, 'cos in theory it'd be recursive, though in practice it wouldn't be, but either way it doesn't sound like what one would want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `PATH` command, just add your path(s) after `%PATH%`, without any quotation marks, dividing distinct items with semicolons:

```
PATH %PATH%;path1;path2
```

It doesn't matter whether your paths contain spaces or not, they will be added just as you have typed them.

Also it doesn't matter whether you terminate the list with a semicolon or not.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in double qutoes and end with ;

> %PATH%;"C:\Program Files\K-Lite Codec Pack\Media Player Classic";"C:\Program Files\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell";